# Why is it necessary to both autowire and initialize a method in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot and have Autowired an @Component annotated class into my Application class. In the main method, I am then trying to call a method on this Autowired class. However, when I call a method from this Autowired class, it tells me that it 'cannot be resolved'.

What is the point of autowiring a class if you have to instantiate it like you would if it wasn't autowired? Doesn't this make autowiring unnecessary?

My application class that produces the error is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CodeWarsApplication {

    @Autowired
    CodeChallenges codechallenge;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        codechallenge.testMethod();     
        SpringApplication.run(CodeWarsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the @Component class is:

```
@Component
public class CodeChallenges {
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Conversely, the method will run if it's structured like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CodeWarsApplication {

    static CodeChallenges codechallenge;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        codechallenge = new CodeChallenges();
        codechallenge.testMethod();     
        SpringApplication.run(CodeWarsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So I am confused what does autowiring even exist if isn't doing anything?

Comment: With auto-wiring you wouldn't have to use the `new` keyword. You just tell the container where you want the object and then in turn it would inject it for you. The compilation error is caused because you cannot access a non-static field from a static method.

Comment: if i make the method static it will remove the compilation error and render the method without the new keyword. Autowiring is still not needed in that context.

Comment: Obviously! Auto-wiring deals with injection of objects by the container. If the method is `static` why would you need an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autowiring isn't working in your case because at the point you are trying to use your bean, the springContext isn't up and hence the dependencies aren't injected.
Try this, use event listener:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CodeWarsApplication {

@Autowired
private CodeChallenges codechallenge;    

public static void main(String[] args) {   
    SpringApplication.run(CodeWarsApplication.class, args);
}

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void callTestMethod() {
      codechallenge.testMethod();   
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! What is that event listener class doing?

Comment: that basically ensure the application context is established, so the autowiring will actually work

Comment: It waits for the application to startup and this method is called then.